# Jquery api doc usage missing

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

All, I saw a lot code samples like below in the Jquery api doc.
`$(someselector).somemethod({somehandle:function( event, ui ) {}});`
For example: you can check [here](http://api.jqueryui.com/selectable/#event-selected).
But I just can't understand how to use the `event` and `ui` parameters of the `function`,and how to get the event target object. Can we just use `this` to refer to it? There is no more details about this in jquery doc. Hope someone can tell me more about it . Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `event` and `ui` variables are parameters on the callback function. Just specify them in the parameter list and you will have access in the function.

```
$( ".selector" ).selectable({
  selected: function( event, ui ) {
    event.foo();
    ui.bar();
  }
});
```

If you're wondering how to use this information you can place a breakpoint in your browser's javascript debugger and inspect the object or my favourite method recently is to use `console.log(event);` and then run it in Chrome and you get the object and it's members available in the console.

[image: Chrome console.log]

[See on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TvKZe/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="selector">
    <span>1</span>
    <span>2</span>
    <span>3</span>
    <span>4</span>
    <span>5</span>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(".selector").selectable({
    selected: function (event, ui) {
        console.log(event);
        console.log(ui);
    }
});
```

Comment: hi, friend, why did I got `object {}` for the `ui` parameter. thanks. I test it in the firebug.

Answer (score 1):

You get the target with `event.target` see http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object. The `ui` parameter contains the currently selected element, as stated in the api reference.

Comment: hi ,@gpasci, friend , seems you got something wrong , event.target is the parent of the selected item. and ui parameter is `object{}` which I got it in firebug. please check it or fix your answer .thanks.

Comment: actually you are right, in this case the children events are delegated to the parent, btw a good console print always helps clarify the situation